# SSH session - why bash FOR loop is not even showing value and also using LOCAL machine

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, ssh, sh

I'm running this SSH command:

```
ssh -p 2001 -q root@12.13.14.15 \
  " echo
    echo Now On Target Server, I see
    ls -l /tmp/Folder-1.1.0.1053/*
    for v in A B C ; do
      echo === $v===
    done
    echo
    for f in /tmp/Folder-1.1.0.1053/* ; do
      echo File is == $f
    done
  "
```

and it's printing this:

```
Now On Target Server, I see
-rw------- 1 root root 159790 Jan 23 17:03 /tmp/Folder-1.1.0.1053/file1-1.8.30.tar.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 116731 Jan 23 17:03 /tmp/Folder-1.1.0.1053/file2-2.7.49.tar.gz
=== ===
=== ===
=== ===

File is ==
File is ==
```

I have a few questions:

1. Why doesn't the first `for` loop print the values of the variable `$v`?
2. Why (when I see the target server have valid files in `/tmp/<folder>`) the second `for` loop did not print the values of the `$f` variable?
3. How can I get the second `for` loop to print the two `.tar.gz` files?
4. I tried `$(...)` or using back quotes to wrap the input values (for `for` loop) in the second `for` loop but it has no effect. For some reason, it's expecting those `*` files using the local machine. Why?

If it's relevant, my Bash version is "GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)", and my Linux version is "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)".

Answer (score 2):

Because you're wrapping your ssh command with double quotes, all your `$` variables are being interpolated by the local shell before going over the wire to the remote shell. Either use single quotes or escape your `$` sigils.

Ex:

```
ssh -p 2001 -q root@12.13.14.15 "echo; echo Now On Target Server, I see; ls -l /tmp/Folder-1.1.0.1053/*; for v in A B C; do echo === \$v===; done; echo; for f in /tmp/Folder-1.1.0.1053/*; do echo File is == \$f; done"
```

or

```
ssh -p 2001 -q root@12.13.14.15 'echo; echo Now On Target Server, I see; ls -l /tmp/Folder-1.1.0.1053/*; for v in A B C; do echo === $v===; done; echo; for f in /tmp/Folder-1.1.0.1053/*; do echo File is == $f; done'
```

See very Important note below. Escape only the variable created and used within the SSH session (ex: `for` loop here) or any where inside SSH session. Do **NOT** escape a variable which was defined in your script and outside of SSH session, ex: as used in the command / input part in `for` loop. i.e. `for v in ${staging_area}/*.tar.gz; do echo ==\$v;done"` here I escaped `\$v` but did not escape `${staging_area}`

Comment: Zeeesus! Thanks.

Comment: So very important NOTE here.. If using double quote with `SSH`, make sure a user is escaping `$v` or `$f` type of variables i.e. any variable within the `for` or similar loop. You `Must NOT` backslash variables using in the conditional / command part of the `for` loop itself. Ex: `for v in ${staging_area}/*.tar.gz; do echo \$v; done` here I didn't escape `staging_area` variable or it'll leave `//*.tar.gz` as `for` loop's input.

Comment: Don't keep adding to the answer - your comments are fine, they'll still be readable to later people.