# How to retrieve value of $(nproc) for a different machine

Tags: linux, unix, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to retrieve number of processors in Edge node through my bash script running on Data Node (different machine). I use ssh to connect with Edge Node in the script.
echo $(nproc) on EdgeNode Machine yields 12
echo $(nproc) on DataNode Machine yields 55

I have tried options as the code given below and also by escaping the $ character like: echo \$(nproc)

nproc_EN=`ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveDevices=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 ${edgeUser}@${edgeHost} "echo $(nproc)"`

Expected: 12
Actual: 55

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH session - why bash FOR loop is not even showing value and also using LOCAL machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333237/ssh-session-why-bash-for-loop-is-not-even-showing-value-and-also-using-local-m)

Comment: 2

Thank you @Tanktalus Because I was wrapping my ssh command with double quotes,  $ variables was being interpolated by the local shell before going over the wire to the remote shell. I wrapped with single quotes and it worked.